# Brown dwarf cloud models

Tags: modeling

There has been research that suggests that the changing brightness of Brown Dwarves are due to bands of Iron/Silicate clouds. Several models have been made that supports that hypothesis. My question is: Which part of the model are the actual clouds? Are the clouds the bright orange bits? Or are those bright areas “breaks” in the clouds and a view of the Brown Dwarf below?

[image: Brown Dwarf Cloud Model]

[image: Artist Rendition]